# Theming the Text Editor selection color

Tags: customization, text-editor

Can the color in the scroll bar for where the active selection is be changed? I have changed the default red selection color, but the indicator in the scroll bar is still red. That indicator in the scroll bar is what I want to change. The image below shows my question.
[image: selection color]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's controlled by the cursor color:

[image]

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to control the opacity.